# How can I get the minimum width an HTML document 'needs' using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using "wkhtmltoimage" to render images of HTML pages. Due to bugs in "wkhtmltoimage" (where it sometimes sets the page width to 32768 pixels), I need to be able to accurately establish how much the ideal page width should be.

Things like headers can stretch to fill available width, so straightforward document body width values are not helpful.

Is there any means with JavaScript (or jQuery) to determine what the best width should be?

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight`

Comment: `screen` is global variable. availWidth and availHeight return the current window width and heigth, resectively.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want the width of my window, I want the width at the point where a horizontal scrollbar is deemed necessary. availWidth is the width of my window, not the minimum width needed to render the content.

Comment: Ok. you can set the width of the element to a certain minimum width, then enable the scroll bars for that element:

`.elmentClass
{
    min-width: 500px;
    overflow: auto; /*or scroll*/
}
`

Comment: Imagine a document with one image in it. That is all it has. How do I know what the minimum width of my browser can be without directly referencing the image width property?